# Loading PHP classes by just putting files into PSR-4 directory

Tags: php, static, php-7, autoload

In my current lib, I have classes with static code outside the class definition, that I would like to execute when browsing a `index.php` file that has autoloading (with properly putting the class files into a PSR-4 folder structure, and calling `composer install` before).

It's not such a bad deal. For instance, in my custom `Error.php` class I could for instance call `set_error_handler` function outside the class so warnings could be catchable. And putting this file in a PSR-4 autoloading could ease the pain for not having to call any `Error.php` code in `index.php` to enable this catching. Every source that just uses my namespace and autoloads my lib would have that for granted.

I tried to include `use \MyNamespace\Error;` in the `index.php` file, but the code in `Error.php`, outside the Error class definition, isn't automatically executed.

The code outside the class **is only executed when I call a class method inside my `index.php` file (the one that has the autoloading)**.

Can this be done ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use \MyNamespace\Error;` does not trigger autoloading, it just allows you to use shorter class name in code - `new Error()` instead of `new \MyNamespace\Error()`. If you want to include `Error.php` file, you need to use this class. Probably the safest way would to use [`class_exist()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php):

```
class_exists(Error::class);
```

But honestly you should rethink your design, implicit registering error handler in file with class declaration is against [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and may be really annoying in big project.

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both
>
> <sub>https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#23-side-effects</sub>

It would be less magical if you create separate method for registering error handler and call it explicitly in `index.php`:

```
Error::registerErrorHandler();
```

Comment: Hi @rob006, your less magical solution is the way I decided to go yesterday, before your reply. Glad to have a second thought. Thanks!